# Magento 2 - Get Collection using custom product Ids and also sort them as the same order as product Ids passed

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, product-collection, product-sorting

I need to get the `collection` using custom `product Ids` but it should sort the collection based on the sequence product Ids given

Here is what I am doing now, but it is not sorting in sequence

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIdsarray));
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to add order along with your `addAttributeToFilter`

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIdsarray ));
$collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(e.entity_id, ".implode(",",$productIdsarray).")"));
```

Comment: Thanks Will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Hurray! It worked

Comment: @Muhammad Hasham, Thanks a lot. It's working

Comment: It's not working in Magento 2.4.1 Version